# Ubuntu 10.04 to 12.04 = PostgreSQL 7.4 database replaced by empty 9.1

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, upgrade

In the process of upgrading our ubuntu 10.04 server to 12.04, PostgreSQL was upgraded from 7.4 to 9.1 without warns. How can I do now to retrieve the old tables from the 7.4 cluster and import them in the 9.1 one? There's no 7.4 binaries packages in the 12.04 repositories...
Thanks

Comment: There's no 7.4 binaries in ubuntu 10.04 either. postgresql-7.4 dates backs from 7-8 years ago. Possibly you meant postgresql-8.4 which indeed was part of ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: It's effectively an old 7.4 install running on a 10.04 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dump the databases *first* and then upgrade. You need a running database server to dump the databases.

You will also probably experience problems jumping quite so many versions in one go, if your databases are of any size or complexity.

Have a look in /var/lib/postgresql - if you have  directory called 7.4 then that's your old database.

Either:

1. Install 10.04 on a spare box, copy the 7.4 dir onto it, start the DB, dump database.
2. Compile 7.4 from source and use that to dump your databases.

I'd go with option 1 if it seems viable.

Ideally you would dump the databases with a later version of pg_dump. If you can install 8.x on ubuntu 10.04 that would be worthwhile.